# Can't installing RPM package intltool?

Tags: rhel, rpm

I want to install on my Linux Red Hat machine (6.3 64 bit) the rpm - `intltool-0.41.0-1.1.el6.src.rpm`.

For some unclear reason I get this:

```
 /var/tmp]# rpm -i  intltool-0.41.0-1.1.el6.src.rpm
 warning: intltool-0.41.0-1.1.el6.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
 warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
 warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
 warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
 warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
 warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
 warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
 /var/tmp]# rpm -qa | grep -i  intltool
 /var/tmp]#
```

#### Questions

- What's the problem?
- How can I fix this?

Comment: The problem seems to be you are using the wrong tool. `rpm` has very limited use for the novice admin - mainly to install extra repositories. For everything else, you should be using `yum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

intltool-0.41.0-1.1.el6.**src.rpm** is a source RPM package, containing the source code, patches and build instructions used to make the actual RPM intltool-0.41.0-1.1.el6.**rpm** package.

IIRC source RPM packages get installed in the `/usr/src/` sub-directories, but if you weren't planning on building your own packages, you should simply download the correct binary package and install that, or use `yum install intltool`.

Comment: Can you help me to find the latest rpm for red-hat 6.3 64bit? ( I cant use yum command )

Comment: Is it not on your install medium?

Comment: What's gone wrong with your `yum`? Your system is badly broken.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed intltool-0.41.0-1.1.el6.**src.rpm**.
It's a package for building rpm from sources and the information about that package not registered in RPM DB.
Look into /usr/src/packages - you can find all the files from src.rpm here.
Now you can build binary rpm package:

```
cd /usr/src/packages/SPECS
rpmbuild -bb intltool.spec
```

Or simply download and install binary package intltool-0.41.0-1.1.el6.rpm (with yum or manually).